# SonarQube server [https://localhost:9000] can not be reached in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I want to build a code coverage from sonarqube in Jenkins. The project is from github. I have configure everything that are necessary but the following errors still arise. Can someone please help me to solve this?

```
Established TCP socket on 59508
[OData] $ java -cp "D:\Program Files\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar;D:\downloads\apache-maven-3.5.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;D:\downloads\apache-maven-3.5.4/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main D:\downloads\apache-maven-3.5.4 "D:\Program Files\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.21.1.jar" "D:\Program Files\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven35-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar" "D:\Program Files\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar" 59508
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\Program Files\workspace\OData\pom.xml clean sonar:sonar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< OData:OData >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building OData 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ OData ---
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< OData:OData >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building OData 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar (default-cli) @ OData ---
[INFO] User cache: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
[ERROR] SonarQube server [https://localhost:9000] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.056 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-27T00:09:08+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar (default-cli) on project OData: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\Program Files\workspace\OData\pom.xml to OData/OData/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/OData-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
channel stopped
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
Skipping sonar analysis due to bad build status FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

for your OData project, when your way to scan the code is via jenkins, you have to set in the settings of jenkins with the hostname, ***don´t recommend put "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"***

Try with **$HOSTNAME**:

1. Go to Settings in Jenkins
2. Move to "Sonarqube Servers"
3. SonarQube servers
   -- Sonarqube instalations
   --- ie: http://myserversonarqube:9000

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Error below is self explanatory. I have below questions

1. Is Sonarqube running on localhost with port 9000 as Secured (i.e https) ?
2. Which version of maven you are using? sometimes some of the  Sonar plugin versions does not work with old maven versions.

   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven- 
   plugin:3.4.1.1168:sonar (default-cli) on project OData: Unable to execute SonarQube: 
   Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR]

Comment: 1. Yes. Is it because that I didn't configure it properly? But I have configured it in "manage jenkins" -> "configure system"
2. I use version 3.5.4. Does it support sonar?